# CentOS 7 Malware? - User "impress+" executes a command ("cron") with a high CPU consumption

Tags: centos, security, malware, chkrootkit

One of my "CentOS 7" servers is showing very *strange behavior*. A user named "**impress+**" executes a command called "**cron**". This "cron" command is executed with a **high CPU consumption**.

I worry because I suspect it may be **malware**...

This server has nothing installed, just "sshd" running.

[image: Top output!]

**QUESTION:** What can I do to find out more about this "impress+" user and this "cron" command?

**Thanks! =D**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately my server is **infected**... =\

Part of the Chkrootkit security utility output ( http://www.chkrootkit.org/ )...

NOTE: Information confirmed via system analysis!

```
[...]
Searching for Linux.Xor.DDoS ... INFECTED: Possible Malicious Linux.Xor.DDoS installed
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/lib/64/libc.so.6
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/lib/64/libpthread.so.0
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/lib/64/tsm
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/lib/32/libc.so.6
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/lib/32/libpthread.so.0
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/lib/32/tsm
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/lib/arm/libc.so.6
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/lib/arm/libpthread.so.0
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/lib/arm/tsm
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/slow
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/tsm
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/watchdog
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/run
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/go
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/tsm32
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/tsmv7
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/start
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/tsm64
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/stop
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/v
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/golan
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/dir.dir
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/n
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/aptitude
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/init
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/init2
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/initall
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/a/anacron
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/a/run
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/a/stop
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/a/a
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/a/cron
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/a/init0
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/b/run
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/b/stop
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/b/a
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/1
/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/dir.dir
[...]
```

**ACTIONS TAKEN:** Destroy the compromised server. Change "root" passwords in the local Infrastructure. Change passwords for users able to run as "root".

**TIP:** Chkrootkit is installed and configured by the **private_tux** tool ( https://github.com/eduardolucioac/private_tux ). It installs and configures security utilities and performs various security diagnostics automatically.

Disclosure: I am the author of private_tux.

Comment: Hi and welcome! This looks like your own tool. If you mention your own tool in your posts, [our rules require](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) that you clearly state that it is your tool. Please ensure you always do this because otherwise, your posts will be deleted as spam by the system.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the information! Change accepted. I take this opportunity to clarify that private_tux has no commercial purpose (BSD-3-Clause license). Thanks! = D

Comment: Oh, I don't doubt that! It's just that the post was flagged as spam and we have rather specific requirements about disclosure here, so I thought I'd let you know. It was perfectly clear to me you were _not_ trying to spam here, don't worry. You did nothing wrong, you could not have known the rules :)